# Prevent PHP date() from defaulting to 12/31/1969

Tags: php, date, default

I am using a MySQL database with PHP. I store my date values in the database using the `DATETIME` field.

I'm using this PHP code to convert inputted dates to the appropriate format for MySQL.

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($inputDate))
```

However, whenever a date is invalid, it is placed in the database as `1969-12-31 19:00:00`

Is there a way to default this to `0000-00-00 00:00:00` ?

Answer (score 16):

Just detect validity with the output of `strtotime()`, which [returns `false` on failure](https://www.php.net/strtotime#function.strtotime.examples).

Something like:

```
$time = strtotime($inputDate);
$date = ($time === false) ? '0000-00-00 00:00:00' : date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time);
```

Answer (score 2):

strtotime is returning false which date evals as 0.  Before you should check that strtotime is not returning false to prevent that:

```
$ts = strtotime($inputDate);

if ($ts === false)
{
//invalid date
}
else
{
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $ts);
}
```