# What could cause a MySQL time stamp to equal December 31, 1969

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

In a PHP site I am running the users table has a datetime field named user_last_login.

I have noticed from time to time for random users that this field has a value of December 31, 1969 while the thousands of other users still have an accurate date stored.

The following PHP code is used to generate this value upon login:

```
$login_success_query->bindValue(':user_last_login', date("Y-m-d H:i:s"), PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

What could potentially be causing this unexpected default date value?

Edit (display code):

```
$user_last_login = strtotime($enrolled_user['user_last_login']);
$user_last_login = date( 'F j, Y | g:i a', $user_last_login );
```

Comment: Let us see the code which ***displays*** this stored date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Longer a **Wild Shot**

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
```

So you are storing a date in proper MySQL date time format. And your display shows sometimes

```
December 31, 1969
```

That means  you are obviously ***displaying*** it  in a different format. So the code you use to convert that date has an issue. Most probably the issue is whether month comes first or day comes first. Look at that code and you will see what this is happening when your code is taking a date for a month and which results in an error which then defaults the printed date to unix epoch.

You can also verify this hypothesis by running a query to see all the stored datetime values and if you are always using `date("Y-m-d H:i:s")` to store the date then it is absolutely impossible for it to ***corrupt*** sometimes randomly.

**Last Login: *Never* ;)** is the answer.

Comment: Oks so there you go. If a user has no last login value then you will see that 1970 date. You should put some error checking there. For example if its the first login by user there will be no prior value.

Comment: thanks, you are correct. turns out field value is null for those who have registered but not logged in - will add error checking

Answer (score 1):

If you convert an epoch (the number of seconds since the *epoch*) to a date, you usually get a nice reasonable value:

For example:

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', 1453266106); //2016-01-20 00:01:46
```

However if you pass in 0, you get the date of the epoch:

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', 0); // 1969-12-31 19:00:00
```

Check your code for any other locations, where you are updating `user_last_login`, and passing in a second (integer) argument to `date`

Answer (score -1):

Looks like your time might be occasionally invalid. See [Prevent PHP date() from defaulting to 12/31/1969](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224097/prevent-php-date-from-defaulting-to-12-31-1969).

You could try first checking the time (like the link indicates) before inserting it to prevent this. But you still need to figure out why it is sometimes invalid. For that, you'd need to understand better where the time is coming from.

Comment: the time is coming from the function posted: date("Y-m-d H:i:s"). Or do you mean something else?

Comment: Yes, the date() function is getting system time. But where is it coming from? Presumably it's getting it from the network (Internet). Maybe your system time is not getting consistent updates and is providing bad values occasionally. This could be hard to debug, but you might be able to check for this in your PHP code prior to inserting the time, and maybe have re-call the date() function again if need be.